# what about sunlight kills vampires vitamin D or the uv rays?

Tags: vampire

Due to a discussion about why people feel cruddy when a day is overcast, I got to thinking is it really the UV light from the sun that kills a vampire?  We all know that UV light is a source of vitamin D, which is a source of energy for humans, having an overcast sky blocks the UV rays, preventing the intake of vitamin D.  However, this same light is what kills a vampire, yet, in many movies/books, vampires are able to move around during the day time if there is cloud cover or the sky is overcast.  Bram Stroker's Dracula was able to operate during the day.  If I remember correctly(it's been a while since I read the books) in the Chronicles of Lestat books and Interview with the Vampire series of books, Louie and Lestat were able to move around during the day time if there was cloud cover.  The same goes in the movie Van Helsing, they could move about hinderless as long as there was cloud cover.  Even in the Twilight series(someone shoot me for even referencing this) the vampires wouldn't sparkle if there was cloud cover.

So, with that said.  Along with UV light sources and other deadly objects to them.  **which is deadly to the vampire the uv rays or the vitamin D??**  All of the natural sources of it are deadly to the vampire, so if I were to sneak a multi-vitamin to a vampire and convince him/her to take it.  Would said vampire burst into flames as if he/she were standing in sunlight?

Comment: In which universe? The vampires you've described (Van Helsing, Bram Stoker, Lestat, Twilight) are incredibly different creatures.

Comment: It's a more in general question since they all(except Twilight) pretty much share the same basic rules in vampire mythology.

Comment: Downvoting.   This is not a constructive question for this site.   Unless you have some reason to suspect this exists in some canon, it is just your own fan theory.   Furthermore, without specifying which universe, it definitely can't have a unique answer.    Take this question to another site!    You have enough rep to know this.

Comment: The vampire mythology is not science-fiction, so it's pointless to try to slap a scientific explanation over one of its components.  You cannot see the reflection of vampire in a mirror, so will you try to find some scientific explanation for that, too? As to Bram Stroker's Dracula, there is nothing special about sunlight; only that he loses many of his magicial powers during the day, weither or not that there are clouds, making him therefore a much easier target to kill. It's only later that the burning by direct sunlight (either fatal or not) has been introduced in the mythology.

Comment: As to the Twilight serie, many have accused the author of disgressing about the traditional vampire mythology.  However, even Bram Stroker's Dracula itself is a big disgression over the previous vampire literature and folklore; which was a very popular topic in the 19th century.  This serie has become one of the most popular and successful series of today and its format has been copied by many other authors; therefore she must have done something right.

Comment: @SylvainL it's not science fiction, but it is fantasy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No.** Sunlight is not a source of vitamin D. Exposure to sunlight helps the the skin synthesize vitamin D, but it doesn't come from the sun itself, so there is no reason to think that vitamin D is the reason that vampires are sensitive to sunlight. Also, the synthesis is not instantaneous, so a vampire wouldn't burst into flame immediately in bright sun (or stop sparkling in the shade) if that were the case.

Not to mention the fact that in many of the stories, it is explicity sunlight that affects vampires. Whether or not artificial UV lights have any effect varies by story, and other artificial lighting never does.

If vampires were as violently reactive to vitamin D as they are often shown to be to sunlight, wouldn't they at least get sick from *people* with vitamin D? Maybe they only feed on kids with rickets.